# AngularJS - Ui-router - Redirecting from root state automatically

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I would like simply to redirect from / to /shop each one somebody types the root. I tried with `$state.go` in the controller, but it didn't do the trick. I would like to do it without `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise` (as there are also urls without routing in my web). Any ideas how to do that? Thanks in advance!

```
 app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
 $stateProvider.state('root', {
     url: "/",
     controller: {
         function() {
             $state.go('shop')
         }
     }
 }).state('shop', {
     url: "/shop",
     controller: 'myCtrl',
     templateUrl: "/shopcontent.jsp"
 })
});
```

Comment: Invoke a function in your controller when somebody types root and use $state.go to go to the desired page. Don't forget to inject $state in your controller

Comment: My problem is how to detect in my controller when somebody goes to /

Comment: You can use `$state.current.name` to get the current state name. In this case it will give you 'root'.

Comment: I tried something like this in my controller, but it doesn't seem to work (I made sure that $state was injected) `(function() {
        if ($state.current.name == 'root') {
            $state.go('shop');
        }
    });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your controller should be as below :

```
 controller: function($state) {
               if ($state.current.name == 'root') { 
                  $state.go('shop'); 
               }
             }
```

You need to inject the `$state` inside your controller function.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the `redirectTo` state definition property.

From the ui-router documentation:

> **Synchronously or asynchronously redirects Transitions to a different
>   state/params**
>
> If this property is defined, a Transition directly to this state will
>   be redirected based on the property's value.

https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/interfaces/state.statedeclaration.html#redirectto

**Example:**

```
.state('root', {
      url: "/",
      redirectTo: "shop"  
})
```

**Full working example:** [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZQPXFHQCa4ZWsia5ajuv?p=preview).

If you want any unknown route to redirect to /shop, you could use the following:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/shop');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

On your run function add a listener to the $stateChangeStart so everything the state changes, it will check if it is root then will change to shop:

```
        .run(["$injector", "$rootScope",
                    function($injector, $rootScop) {
                        $rootScope.$state = $injector.get("$state");
                          //-----Track State Change for request Token -------------
                        $rootScope.$stateChangeStart = [];
                        $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart",
                            function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
                                if (fromState.name == "root") {
                                   $state.go('shop')
                               }
                                $rootScope.$stateChangeStart.push({
                                    toState: toState,
                                    toParams: toParams,
                                    fromState: fromState,
                                    fromParams: fromParams
                                });
                            });
                    }
                ]);
```

Comment: I marked the other one as correct as the approach was more simple, but thanks for the insight!